# NextJS websocket proxy(?) to server through docker DNS

Tags: javascript, docker, websocket, docker-compose, next.js

I have an app of `NextJS` frontend server and a backend server(irrelevant in this question), each defined and deployed as `docker-compose` service.

Since the hostname of the backend server is dynamic by docker DNS, I would have to refer to it by its service name on NextJS server, which resolves it on runtime. I use NextJS's `_middleware.ts`, which is essentially a convenient way to define a generic `API Route` as far as I can tell.

This works well for HTTP requests, but for the WebSocket request that initiates the handshake, the `WebSocket` class expects `ws://***` format for the URL argument, which does not go through the NextJS's API Route obviously since it doesn't start with `/api`.

So it's looking like I:

- have to somehow resolve the DNS hostname
- have to use `ws://` format

, and it seems these can't be achieved at the same time for NextJS. Am I missing something?